# How to use Helper functions in custom page

Tags: osclass

I have created an ABC.php file in mytheme folder.
Everything works fine but when I use some helper function in it for example
`<?php echo osc_current_web_theme();?>`it do not produce desired output.

The ABC.php page will be called via ajax when need so I do not need complete header and footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following code at the top of the php page will make available helper functions of osclass for this php page.

```
<?php
    define('ABS_PATH', dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))) . '/' );
    require_once ABS_PATH . 'oc-load.php';
?>
```